# Unable to convert this legacy SQL into Standard SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am not able to validate this legacy sql into standard bigquery sql as I don't know what else is required to change here(This query fails during validation if I choose standard SQL as big query dialect):

```sql
SELECT
  lineitem.*,
  proposal_lineitem.*,
  porder.*,
  company.*,
  product.*,
  proposal.*,
  trafficker.name,
  salesperson.name,
  rate_card.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    dfp_data.dfp_order_lineitem
  WHERE
    DATE(end_datetime) >= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'YEAR'))
    OR end_datetime IS NULL ) lineitem
JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    dfp_data.dfp_order) porder
ON
  lineitem.order_id = porder.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    adpoint_data.dfp_proposal_lineitem) proposal_lineitem
ON
  lineitem.id = proposal_lineitem.dfp_lineitem_id
JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    dfp_data.dfp_company) company
ON
  porder.advertiser_id = company.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    adpoint_data.dfp_product) product
ON
  proposal_lineitem.product_id=product.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    adpoint_data.dfp_proposal) proposal
ON
  proposal_lineitem.proposal_id=proposal.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    adpoint_data.dfp_rate_card) rate_card
ON
  proposal_lineitem.ratecard_id=rate_card.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    name
  FROM
    dfp_data.dfp_user) trafficker
ON
  porder.trafficker_id =trafficker.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    name
  FROM
    dfp_data.dfp_user) salesperson
ON
  porder. salesperson_id =salesperson.id
```

Comment: First of all, re-arrange your code snip in an easy to read one. Secondly, what do you mean by standard-sql? It seems ok.

Comment: @Edward Aung when we paste above query in big query editor with query settings as legacy, it works fine. However if your big query editor is using standard-sql (a big query sql dialect type), it fails during validation.

Comment: What is the error? We can't see your screen...

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant apologies for late response, I have marked your answer as accepted one. Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error you are getting is something like below

```
Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): name
```

Legacy SQL adjust `trafficker.name` and `salesperson.name` in your SELECT statement into respectively `trafficker_name` and `salesperson_name` thus effectively eliminating column names duplication

Standard SQL behaves differently and treat both those columns as named `name` thus producing duplication case. To avoid it - you just need to provide aliases as in example below

```
SELECT
  lineitem.*,
  proposal_lineitem.*,
  porder.*,
  company.*,
  product.*,
  proposal.*,
  trafficker.name AS trafficker_name,
  salesperson.name AS salesperson_name,
  rate_card.*
FROM ( ...
```

You can easily check above explained using below simplified/dummy queries

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  porder.*,
  trafficker.name,
  salesperson.name
FROM (
  SELECT 1 order_id, 'abc' order_name, 1 trafficker_id, 2 salesperson_id
) porder
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 id, 'trafficker' name) trafficker
  ON porder.trafficker_id =trafficker.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 id, 'salesperson' name ) salesperson
  ON porder. salesperson_id =salesperson.id
```

and

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  porder.*,
  trafficker.name AS trafficker_name,
  salesperson.name AS salesperson_name
FROM (
  SELECT 1 order_id, 'abc' order_name, 1 trafficker_id, 2 salesperson_id
) porder
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 id, 'trafficker' name) trafficker
  ON porder.trafficker_id =trafficker.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 id, 'salesperson' name ) salesperson
  ON porder. salesperson_id =salesperson.id
```

Note: if you have more duplicate names - you need to alias all of them too

Comment: Exactly explained what worked for me, thanks a lot.